# font collision in Beamer when using kmath and kerkis together with siunitx, bm, and stmaryrd

Tags: beamer, fonts

I'm trying to create a Beamer presentation with a few packages, and I have a problem when I want to use the kmath, kerkis fonts. I managed to track down the problem to some packages (siunitx, bm, and stmaryrd). The error message is that I have way too many math fonts. I do need these last packages, so I was wondering if I can still use kmath/kerkis fonts. This is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}, fleqn]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}

\usepackage{bm} % for bold symbols
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for SI units


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile, label=IGFEM]
$a+b=c$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set

```
\newcommand\bmmax{0}
\newcommand\hmmax{0}
```

before loading the `bm` package to save font families being used.  This will not inhibit the functionality of the package:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}, fleqn]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}

\newcommand\bmmax{0}
\newcommand\hmmax{0}
\usepackage{bm} % for bold symbols
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for SI units


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile, label=IGFEM]
  $a+b=c$

  \( \bm{\mathit{a}} + \bm{\mathit{b}} = \bm{\mathit{c}} \)
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```